# ¿Cómo crear una extensión en Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, make

He creado un pequeño motor para PostgreSQL (no sé si ni siquiera podría llamarlo así) que consiste en un puñado de funciones, tipos y unas tablas predefinidas. Es lo que necesito para una aplicación, cuyo cliente ya está terminado.

Ahora me enfrento a la cuestión de instalar este conjunto de funciones/tipos/tablas en otro ordenador. Para ello, creo que la mejor forma de hacerlo es crear una [extensión](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/extend-extensions.html) de forma que todo el proceso quede bien empaquetado, y además pueda quitar, o actualizar el conjunto siempre que quiera y en cualquier ordenador.

Bueno, pues siguiendo este [tutorial](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/04/05/writing-postgresql-extensions-is-fun-c-language/) hago un ejemplo previo para ver si me funciona.

Tengo mi archivo .sql con las funciones/tipos y demás (en este caso del ejemplo solo una pequeña función):

**log.0.0.1.sql**

```
CREATE FUNCTION di_hola()
RETURNS VOID
AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE ('Hola');
END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION sdmed.di_hola()
  OWNER TO sdmed;
```

Creo el archivo de control:
**log.control**

```
comment = 'PostgreSQL Funcion Hola'
default_version = '0.0.1'
relocatable = true
# module_pathname = '$libdir/log'
module_pathname = '/usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib/'
schema = sdmed
```

(Como se puede ver en el código, he cambiado la línea module_`pathname = '$libdir/log'` por `module_pathname = '/usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib/'` "hardcodeando" la ruta y pensando que tal vez ese fuera el error...en todo caso no funciona en ambos casos.

Y por último el Makefile

```
EXTENSION = log
MODULE_big = log
DATA = log--0.0.1.sql
OBJS = log.o 

PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

Ahora solo quedaría compilar la extensión e instalarla:

```
make USE_PGXS = 1
make USE_PGXS = 1 install
```

Pero me da el error:

> make: *** nombre de variable vacío.  Alto.

Gracias

**EDITO:**

Primer fallo, no es `make USE_PGXS = 1` sino `make USE_PGXS=1` (sin espacios)

Ahora que hago bien la llamada, veo que me falta `pgxs.mk`
En mi caso -Linux Mint- lo soluciono instalando el paquete `postgresql-server-dev-10`

Sin embargo ahora tengo este error:

> make: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo 'log.o',
>   necesario para 'log.so'.  Alto.

Comment: Si es un archivo .SQL solamente para tu código, con hacer un make install y en el . control es más simple aun, si quieres un ejemplo similar al tuyo puedes observar este https://github.com/asotolongo/db_info

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora entiendo mejor el proceso. El ejemplo que puse no me funcionaba porque tenía algo de C (el ejemplo que copié) y al pasarlo a mi prueba no lo puse. Por lo que veo, lo único que hace make install es copiar el archivo *.sql y *.control a "/usr/share/postgresql/10/extension/" (en mi caso) y dejarlo listo para poder instalar el contenido con la orden CREATE EXTENSION. Realmente no tiene mucho sentido ya mi pregunta, viendo que era un error de concepto. La editaré un poco por no borrarla. Gracias!